# ask using json in xcode4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

Hello I am new in iPhone dev
i want to display select array with json to mysql in xcode4
i have output **json code** in php like this:

```
{"data":[{"id":"16","nama":"yes","desk":"test2","gambar":""}]}
```

and my code module like this:

**list.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AIR = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.169/demo/json/rifle.php"];

    NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(jsonreturn);

    NSData *jsonData =[jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error =nil;

    NSDictionary *dict =[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer]deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
    if (dict) {
        AIR = [[dict objectForKey:@"data"] retain];
    }
    NSLog(@"Array:%@",AIR);
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [AIR count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *dict = [AIR objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // deklarasi image ambil file gambar didalam field nama
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"nama"];

    // deklarasi image ambil file gambar didalam field desk
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"desk"];

    // deklarasi image ambil file gambar didalam field gambar
    UIImage *cellImage =[UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"gambar"]];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;


    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    subway *mAIR = [[subway alloc] initWithNibName:@"subway" bundle:nil];
    [mAIR setTitle:@"AIRGUN DESC DETAIL"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mAIR animated:YES];
    [mAIR release];
}
```

subway is another ViewController with tableView iniNibName subway n now my question how can i get $id (see json code) for select array
if in php like this comment

```
SELECT * FROM data where id="$id"
```

so if i select list NIB they will display output in subway NIB

can help me please

thx before

Comment: Just for info try using JSONKit parser (https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) cos it's blazing fast...

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot parse your question.  Please try to clarify it.

Comment: Here is an example <a href="http://blackberrymastercracks.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-use-json-in-xcode.html">using JSON in xcode</a>.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same and I use SBJSON libraries:

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

- DownloadedData is the JSON you receive from the webservice
- parsedData is the NSDicitonary with the JSON parsed

  ```
  NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

  SBJSON *parser = [SBJSON new];

  NSDictionary *parsedData = (NSDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:responseString error: nil];
  [responseString release];


  [parser release];
  ```

You can find a tutorial here:
http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Comment: can i get refrence about instaling sbjson

Comment: Try this: http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Comment: i am still can't understand ...about that refrence i only want to using like this if i request http://192.168.0.169/demo/json/rifle.php?id=%@

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONKit https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

You need just 2 files (JSONKit.h and JSONKit.m) - copy it into your project
Then you need to import it in you .m file:

```
#import "JSONKit.h"
```

Download your data to NSString *jsonString as you want, and then use:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

It this array you get your response, and now use NSDictionary or NSArray to get variables (depends on data in json response) - NSDictionary is key:value and NSArray is just array of objects.

So to get your ID = 16 from your json response, you need something like:

```
NSLog(@"My ID is %@", [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

You can anytime check content of NSDictionary or NSArray like NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

Or if "data" section is dictionary, use [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"id"]
Because you got dictionary and inside it, is another dictionary structured response.

Comment: How does this differ from what his CJSONDeserializer is presumably doing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplest method for json parsing,hope helps you

**ViewController.h**

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
 {
    NSArray *ids;
    NSArray *nama;
    NSArray *desk;
    NSArray *gambar;

   //=======Json Variable
   NSMutableData *webdata;
   NSURLConnection *conn;
  //======
 }
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.169/demo/json/rifle.php"];
  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
  conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (conn) {
    webdata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  }

}

#pragma NSUrl Connection Delegate
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
     [webdata setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
     [webdata appendData:data];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
      NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[webdata mutableBytes] length:[webdata length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"Data Length %d",[webdata length]);
     NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

    ids = [[result valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"];
    nama = [[result valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"nama"];
    desk = [[result valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"desk"];
    gambar = [[result valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"gambar"];
}
```